# Lua getting line number of the error

Tags: ios, lua

I 've following Lua iOS code:

```
lua_State* s = luaL_newstate();
 luaL_openlibs(s);

 NSString* s2 = ... // some text
 const char* scr = [s2 UTF8String];

 luaL_loadstring(s, scr);
 int err = lua_pcall(s, 0, 0, 0);
 if (err != 0)
     {
     const char* str = lua_tostring(s, -1);
     }
    lua_close(s);
```

Is that the proper way to get the line + error message? It shows a line which is not the error line.

Update: Error line is OK, but the error message always refers to the first line in the script, not the actual error line.

Comment: Show us the error message.

Comment: The error() function can report error on different levels. Check this manual for more details: http://www.lua.org/pil/8.5.html

Comment: I need to check the error from C++, not from Lua.

Comment: Show us the script and the error.